# Why does EXCEL nested IF return FALSE rather than returning a value

Tags: if-statement

[screen shot showing formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwUTU.png)

[screen shot showing results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avzQd.png)

The IF statement in question is the one in G56.

I other cases, I've seen EXCEL display an error message pointing 
out a syntax error but in this case it's not displaying any error.

I've placed some comments in the spreadsheet to explain
what I'm trying to accomplish. Refer to the screenshot.

The IF THEN ELSE code you show is what I want to put 
into effect. I want to translate that to an =IF worksheet 
formula but I don't find a definitive description of the 
=IF syntax.

Using  "trial and error":

1) =IF($D56<>$E56,IF($F55="no",$G55,IF($G55="jan","phil",$G55),$g55))
    result: "you've entered too many arguments for this function"
        and flaged the $g55 argument.

2) =IF($D56<>$E56,IF($F55="no",$G55,IF($G55="jan","phil",if($f55="yes",if($g55="jan","jan","phil")
    result:  "we found a typo in your formula and tried to correct it"

3)
 manually add right-parens before committing the formula
    result: "you've entered too many arguments for this function"
        no argument was flagged in this case
Everything ends up with a formula that returns FALSE.

I tried to find documentation via the help within EXCEL and found
=IF(Something is True, then do something, otherwise do something else)

google search locates(not permitted to show link here)
=IF(Something is True, then do something, otherwise do something else)

Comment: You've only provided 2 arguments to your outer IF.

Comment: You haven't defined what should happen if D56 is equal to E56

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
IF (50.55 <> 50.55) THEN
    IF ('no'='no') THEN
       return 'phil'
    ELSE
       IF ('phil' = 'jan') THEN
           return 'phil'
       ELSE
           return 'phil'
       END IF
    END IF
END IF
```

now, what happens when 50.55 equals 50.55 ?

Comment: I addressed your comment by editing my original question. I think I should have simply addressed it by a comment rather than the edit. I now realize that I can shoulder-tap you by putting your username in my comment. Please take a look at my edit starting with "The IF THEN ELSE code you show is what I want to put into effect."

Comment: @user318814 EXCEL expressions only works with IF (something, true, false) - you forgot the 'false' part. check your code again. in your case, you put another if in the true part, but didn't end up relating to the outer false part.

Comment: I get the logic but I can't find a definitive description of the syntax.